# NHibernate Namespace

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

What namespace do I need to have in my project to execute the command;
ISession.Evict(obj)????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just need `NHibernate` and whatever you're using for proxy like `NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle`.  Should have no problem with ISession with just those.

Note also that you'll need `FluentNHibernate` if you are using any of Fluent's items in the same class.

Comment: @Jamaica ISession is an NHibernate item.  If you have a reference to the above you should have no problem using ISession or the concrete object.  ISession is the interface, Session is the concrete class that implements the interface.  You have to have a concrete instance of Session in order to call the Evict() method.